# C program does not output anything

Tags: c, windows

I've been trying to write a program to find the greatest prime factor of a 600851475143 and I have been running into some difficulties with running the program shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

long long n = 600851475143;
long long largest = 0;

int prime(long long c);

int main()
{
  for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (n % i == 0 && prime(i) == 0)
    {
      largest = i;
    }
  }
  printf("%ll\n", largest);
  return 0;
}

int prime(long long c)
{
  for (long long j = 0; j < c; j++)
  {
    if (c % j == 0)
    {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The program compiles without any errors or warnings but when I run the program, it appears to be running for a few seconds but then finishes without outputting anything, even though there is a printf statement at the end of `main`. I am on Windows using MinGW and gcc if that helps.

Comment: You should think about dividing by the prime factors as you find them (repeatedly, in case the number has the same prime factor multiple time (as in `9` has `3` as a factor, twice).  This reduces the amount of testing you'll need to do.  There are lots of easy steps you can take to improve the performance of the `prime()` function dramatically, starting with using the condition `j * j <= c` instead of `j < c`.

Comment: What’s the exit status of the program? I.e. what does your shell say if you invoke ‘echo $?’  in your MinGW shell window ?

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and about [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

Comment: Don't you get a 'divide by zero' exception in `prime()` because of: `for (long long j = 0; j < c; j++)
  {
    if (c % j == 0)` On the first iteration, `j` is 0 so you divide by 0, and integer division by zero is definitely a Bad Thing™.  You should be starting the loop at `2`, not `0`.  Even if you don't get divide by zero problems, you also try dividing by `1`, and every integer except `0` leaves a zero remainder when you divide by 1.  However, the absence of a result strongly suggests a divide by zero error.

Comment: Your code compiled, but when i ran it i got "Floating point exception". You must be dividing by 0 somewhere.

Comment: Try to start the for loops from 2! The algorithms that you're using are not the better possible. You may adjust `prime` considering that, apart 2, the divisors are odd, and furthermore the divisor search may be attempted till the square root of `n`... (just to start to have a more powerful code).

Comment: The code doesn't display nothing because it's terminates 'cause a division by 0!

Comment: Thanks, with the performance improvements in the prime function and by no longer dividing by 0, the program works as intended.